# rotating image while scrolling - javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, scroll, rotation

I hope you're all right.
I've searched everywhere but I can't find the answer to my problem.
The issue is that I want a logo to rotate while the page is scrolling (this is already achieved), but when I click on a title in the menu, I want the logo to move (as I do now) but when it reaches the element in question, always stays straight, so that you can always see the logo as it should be.
This is the code I have for the scroll and the logo now:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var theta = $(window).scrollTop() / 200;
  $('#header-logo').css({ transform: 'rotate(-' + theta + 'rad'}); 
});
```

I do not have much experience with javascript and much less with jquery.

Thank you!

Comment: Which example @Raymond ?

Comment: It might help to build a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Alfredo, it would great if you can a little more detail of the problem you are dealing with, along with an example ( you can use services such as code pen to host your solution )

As far as I can understand, you can rotate the logo using JS, but when you click on the title in the menu, the logo stays in the same position as it is at that point of the page & doesn't come back to its initial orientation

Comment: If my assumpation is correct, you can recalculate theta & rotate it in opposite direction to retain the animation else you can set it to 0 ( ie setting it to initial orientation ), do let me know if this works for you or not .

Comment: I can show you the website that I am working on... http://movilizate.pragmanet.com.py
As you can see, I have part of the logo rotating, if you click on any menu, it scrolls down, but the part rotating is not staying at the original position... I was thinking on just make it rotate 180º everytime scrolls down